# Multiple scalar products of expanding rows and columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to calculate the scalar product of row B1:1 with row B2:2, B3:3, ..., and put the result in column A. My data can have empty cells and is growing both in columns and rows, therefore I would like to find a solution that does not require applying the formula manually to each new data entry.

My current solution mathematically does what I want. However, whenever there are more rows than columns in the sheet, the result is only calculated for the number of columns and the remaining rows remain empty.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(N(B1:1), N(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(CELL("address", B2)&":"&COLUMNS(2:2)))))))
```

Adding empty columns works for now, but how can I solve this without having to add extra columns all the time?

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HeZCrUQEZFaqgjm0BB54JHDitqFLGtr_24Gwt6i5BRU/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Result is calculated four times because there are 4 columns from B to E]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said

> I would like to calculate the scalar product of row B1:1 with row B2:2, B3:3, ..., and put the result in column A. ...without having to add extra columns all the time?

In your formula use **`max(arrayformula(if(B:B<>"",row(B:B),"")))`**
instead of `COLUMNS(2:2)`

Your **new formula** will be

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(N(B1:1), N(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(CELL("address", B2)&":"&max(arrayformula(if(B:B<>"",row(B:B),"")))))))))
```

[image]

---

**Useful snippet**

**How to find the last non-empty row number in a column**

```
=max(arrayformula(if(B:B<>"",row(B:B),"")))
```

gives the **row number of the last non-empty row in column `B` regardless of empty cells**,

[image]

---

#### EDIT

Please use the following formula to MMULT **ANY number of Rows or Columns
based on just 2 cells**: `B1` and `B2`
*(The altered formula (as given by [mz1000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6944935/mz1000) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005691/multiple-scalar-products-of-expanding-rows-and-columns-in-google-sheets/64006685?noredirect=1#comment113308696_64006685))*

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(N(B1:1), 
                         N(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(CELL("address", B2)&":"&max(arrayformula(
                            if(INDIRECT(CELL("address", B2)&":"&ROWS(B:B))<>"", 
                                  row(INDIRECT(CELL("address", B2)&":"&ROWS(B:B))),"")))))))))
```

Comment: This solves the problem almost completely! Can this be extended to also solve the case where depending on the data the last row entry may exist only in a column other than B (e.g. empty in B but a value in C, D, ...?

Comment: Yes, it does solve the problem. Except the case where column B's last row is empty and another column has a value. Do you mind sharing the solution for this, too?

Comment: *"[Yes, it does solve the problem. Except...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005691/multiple-scalar-products-of-expanding-rows-and-columns-in-google-sheets/64006685?noredirect=1#comment113279115_64006685)"* Have you tried solving it yourself? The second image of my answer shows you the way. In any case. Replace `max(arrayformula(if(B:B<>"",row(B:B)` with `max(arrayformula(if(D:D<>"",row(D:D)` as in https://i.stack.imgur.com/79XKs.png

Comment: I see where our misunderstanding is: In your previous comment it would change the row that is checked for entries from B to D. However, what I am trying to address is that it is not known beforehand where the entries are sparse. With your input I was able to figure it out. Replacing with:
`max(arrayformula(if(INDIRECT(CELL("address", B2)&":"&ROWS(B:B))<>"",row(INDIRECT(CELL("address", B2)&":"&ROWS(B:B))),"")))` does the job. See [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HeZCrUQEZFaqgjm0BB54JHDitqFLGtr_24Gwt6i5BRU/edit#gid=418341151).

Comment: *"I see where our misunderstanding is: In your previous..."*. Now I see it as well. Sorry about that. If you don't mind I could add it in the answer. Many people do not make it this far in the comments.

Comment: Great, please go ahead and include it in the answer, thanks!